# Convert Route Templates into Regex

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have an application with ~300 of services.  I would like to add authorization for a specific subroute.
I've created a custom authorization attribute to to verify routes.  I would like to convert the route templates to regex, so I can assure that any changes in the future will be automatically be applied back to the authorization attribute.

e.g I have a route.

```
var benefitRoute =  "/employees/{employeeId:Guid}/benefit/{benefitId:guid}/enrollments";
```

I would like to replace all of the {} and their contents with .*

```
"/employees/.*/benefit/.*/enrollments";
```

However I tried to match on `\{.+\}`  However it grabs the larger one before the two smaller ones, when I run my regex.

```
Regex.Replace(route, "\{.+\}", ".*");
```

How can I convert the route templates into Regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add '?' which makes quantifiers "lazy", try

```
        var benefitRoute =  "/employees/{employeeId:Guid}/benefit/{benefitId:guid}/enrollments";
        string pattern = @"{(.*?)}";
        String result=Regex.Replace(benefitRoute, pattern, ".*");
```

You can find more info on it here http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html